# Speech Dataset for Spanish ASR

Tags: machine-learning

We are building ASR system for native spanish language. We are looking for the spanish speech datasets to train our model. If anyone can provide the links/sources of spanish speech datasets(paid/free) it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Common Voice project](https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/) from Mozilla. They have an open source dataset of multiple languages, Spanish currently has 324 hours of validated speech data (out of 579 total). You can download the dataset for Spanish and other languages at https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/en/datasets.